# How do I get Gradle to download and cache the scala compiler JARs?

Tags: gradle

I have a `build.gradle` that starts like this:

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "1.2.3"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'application'
```

When I run it inside Docker (in CI), it spends about a minute downloading jars (e.g. the scala compiler jar). Every time I change the source code and rebuild in Docker, the files are downloaded again. To speed this up, I've copied the snippet above and added

```
task download() {}
```

Calling `gradle download` (in a Dockerfile layer) grabs some JARs, but not the scala compiler JARs. How might I get those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to cache Gradle cache locations in `~/.gradle/caches`. If you mount this directory from the host system it will enable you to reuse Gradle caches.

Unfortunately, tasks trigger downloading of artifacts lazily. You can emulate this behavior if you call `getResolvedConfiguration()` method on required dependencies configuration.

Replace `compile` with required configuration name and this call will download all the dependencies:

```
task downloadCompileJars() {
    doLast {
        configurations.getByName('compile').resolvedConfiguration
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not so keen on letting the host OS 'leak' into Docker in any way. It could affect reproducibility in CI. I'm looking for a command to download the dependencies...